# A "simple" number sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

What are the last three numbers in this sequence?

> **6, 8, 92, 88, 32, 53, 106, 88, 6, 63, 60, 68, 15, 75, 16, ___, ___, ___**

This is not an OEIS sequence, nor does solving it require any math.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure the three numbers are

> 16, 92, 75 as these are the atomic numbers of elements S, U, Re

The number sequence becomes

> C O U Ra Ge I Sg  Ra C Eu Nd Er P Re S in [chemical symbols](http://www.lenntech.com/periodic/number/atomic-number.htm)
>
>  "Courage is grace under pressure" is a Hemingway quote.

In the title

> "simple" clues **element**ary.